# Regular expression how to search for () and replace with[]

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Silly question, but I do not know how to find `(2000)` into a regular expression and replace it with `[2000]`

Answer (score 12):

You can do:

```
str.replace(/\((\d+)\)/g, "[$1]");
```

Regex used: `\((\d+)\)`

- `(` and `)` are special char in regex
  used for grouping, to match literal
  `(` `)`, you need to escape them as
  `\(` `\)`
- `\d` is short for a digit. `\d+`
  means one or more digits.
- `(` `)` is to group and remember the
  number. The remembered number will
  later be used in replacement.
- `g` for global replacement. Mean
  every occurrence of the patten in the
  string will be replaced.
- `$1` is the number between `(`
  `)`that was grouped and remembered.
- `/` `/` are the regex delimiters.

Comment: If you want to precise about the number of digits matched, you can add "counters". So you can use \d{3} to only have 3 digits, or \d{2,4} to match anything that's 2 to 4 digits. I've always found this site to be a good, easy to understand reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
function _foo(str) {
   return str.replace(/[(](\d*)[)]/, '[$1]');
}

alert( _foo("(2000)") );  // -> '[2000]'
alert( _foo("(30)") );    // -> '[30]'
alert( _foo("(abc)") );   // -> '(abc)'
alert( _foo("()") );      // -> '[]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: `yourString.replace(/\(2000\)/, "[2000]");`

Comment: Since this is JavaScript, you may want the `/g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function foo(S) { 
    return S.replace(/\(([^\)]+)\)/g,"[$1]");
}
```